# Google Font loader reports loading of font as failed even if the fonts is loaded correctly

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-font-api, webfont-loader

I'm having this strange issue. I'm loading fonts with google font loader.

```
    var data = {
        active: call_resize,
        fontactive: bum,
        fontinactive: bam,
        custom : {
            families : [ 'League Gothic', 'FontAwesome' ],
            urls : [
                    'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes-ai1ec/vortex/less/bootstrap/font-awesome.css',
                    'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes-ai1ec/vortex/less/bootstrap/font-league-gothic.css'
                    ]
        }
    };
    require(
        [ 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js' ],
        function(  ) {
            WebFont.load(data);
        } );
```

Basically the two fonts are loaded correctly but the font loader report the second font as not being loaded correctly while this is not true as you can see from the image.

[image: fonts]

this is really tedious because i need to performa an action when all fonts are loaded and now Firefox and chrome are waiting for the failure before calling the "active" handler.

Comment: I have the same issue. For me it seems that the font that fails is the one that i haven't declared in the CSS yet.